# How Redirect Requests To A PHP File in .HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want all requests to be transferred via a PHP file.

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule . /test.php [L,NE]
```

And My PHP Code:

```
<?php
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']);
?>
```

But without a doubt the result of this code is an infinite loop. The request is given to PHP yy .htaccess. and when PHP redirects the user, the user goes to .htaccess again and again.

Comment: What are you trying to do in PHP file?

Comment: I want to create a web application firewall. Is my method wrong?

Comment: What is your PHP script supposed to do? Where is it supposed to redirect? Currently it's redirecting either to itself or to root, depending on whether `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']` is set.

Comment: ```RewriteRule ^/?(.*) filename [R,L]``` something like this?

Comment: $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = "User URL"; For Example: "User URL" = "mysite.com/index.html". But according to the htaccess code, user is redirect to test.php.And I want to be directed to "mysite.com/index.html"after passing test.php.

Comment: I just want to use PHP as a firewall

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Next, you process the request already in your index.php.
No need to use another redirect in php file